# Cannot add a child that doesn't have a YogaNode to a parent without a measure function

Tags: react-native

I am getting this error in my react native code.

> Cannot add a child that doesn't have a YogaNode to a parent without a measure function! (Trying to add a 'RCTRawText' [text:] to a 'RCTView')

Versions that I am using:

```
"react-native-cli" : 2.0.1
"react-native" : 0.55.3
"react-navigation" : 1.5.12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably left some text outside of a tag:

```
<View>
    ERROR
</View>

<View>
    <Text>
       CORRECT
    </Text>
</View>
```

Comment: ,Thank you for your help. This solution helped me.